# Changing the color of a specific curve in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color

How do I change the color of a specific curve in my `ContourPlot`? I want to change the color of the last curve (+1.5 additive factor) from `purple` to `gray`. Here's my code:

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x] - 1.5, 
  Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x] - 1, Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x], 
  Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x] + 1, 
  Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x] + 1.5}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 
  2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Combine separate plots with `Show` is one simple way that comes to mind.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you! @MichaelE2

Comment: Or `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[(Sin[2 y] == -2/3 Cos[3 x] - #) & /@ {-3/2, -1, 0, 1, 
    3/2}],
 {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
   LightGray},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` where I have used `LightGray` rather than `Gray` to make the difference easier to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two more methods in addition to the ones mentioned in comments by Michael E2 and Bob Hanlon:

1. Post-process `Purple` (actually, `ColorData[97][5]`) to `Gray`:

```
contours = {-3/2, -1, 0, 1, 3/2};
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sin[2 y] + 2/3 Cos[3 x] == # & /@ contours],
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}] /. 
    Directive[___, ColorData[97][5], ___] :> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Gray]
```

[image]

2. Use a single function and style the contours using the `{{contour1, style1}..}` form for setting the option `Contours`:

```
styles = Append[ColorData[97] /@ Range[4], Directive[Thick, Gray]];
ContourPlot[Sin[2 y] - 2/3 Cos[3 x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> Thread[{contours, styles}], ContourShading -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[styles, Sin[2 y] - 2/3 Cos[3 x] == # & /@ contours]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great.